# How to log when a process exits or is restarted?

Tags: gnome, process, logging, monitoring

I am trying to track down a bug in `gnome-shell` which causes it to crash, I seem to have two instances running of `gnome-shell` and apparently this is meant to be so. For the best results in my debugging I need to know specifically which one is crashing and it doesn't tell me anywhere.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, is there a way of 'watching' and logging when one of the two exists or is restarted? I will be able to provide it with the PIDs of both, I just need a log of when one of them exits.

Comment: your best bet I think is to make a script and run that in a terminal so that when it crashed the terminal shows it :) so that you can note the time

Comment: @patrick: Sorry, but how exactly do you suggest I check if it's crashed or not? Or perhaps we are misunderstanding each other?

Comment: you see, when I am debugging one of my programs I simply make a shell script and execute that with xterm, lets say this is your script

` #!/bin/bash
  gnome-shell `

then execute that with 

`xterm` using `bash /path/to/the/script`